# Identifying characters

Tags: буквы

I took this picture at the Pere Lachaise Cemetery in Paris. I'm a graphic designer and I'm curious about this typography, I think it's cyrillic writing or maybe an old alphabet, I could be wrong. I already tried to match each shape with the cyrillic alphabet but I was unable to get them all.

It's cyrillic? What characters are? Any idea about the meaning?

[image]

I already draw some of them:

[image]

Another pic:

[image]

Comment: Been there. Whose grave is this? Most Russians are on St.Genevieve de Bois..

Comment: Cimetiere [Pere Lachaise](https://www.google.es/maps/@48.8606747,2.3912009,17z), Paris

Comment: This I figured from the question :) I was wondering (if this text is on a grave) - who is buried under this text?

Comment: It's a small mausoleum in a corner, at the Gambetta street side. I added another picture I had at the question.

Comment: someone there was really frond of John's Gospel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like

> А́щє лю́битє м[iа́](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iotated_A), за́повѣди мо[iа́](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iotated_A) соблюди́тє ([Ин. 14:15](http://archive.is/HfXsa))
>
> If you love me, keep my commands  ([John 14:15](https://www.biblestudytools.com/john/14-15.html))

Comment: Which language is that? Old Church Slavonic or something else not Russian?

Comment: @Wilson yes, Church Slavonic, the liturgical language of the Russian Orthodox Church

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Cyrillic_alphabet), it's an older version of cyrillic.